# Why won't my UITableView Display?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have googled and searched here on stackoverflow, but haven't been able to find a solution.

**What I expect to happen:** UITableView to display and show cells containing "hi"

**What happens:** UITableView doesn't even display

*viewViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface viewViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
//note: the above property is connected to my UITableViewController

@end
```

*viewViewController.m*

```
#import "viewViewController.h"

@interface viewViewController ()

@end

@implementation viewViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (!_tableView){

        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    return _tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    //[self setTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"asking for rows");
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return 5;
        case 1:
            return 10;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"hi";
    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"testtext";
}


@end
```

Please tell me what I have done wrong and correct my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add some protocols to your view controller:

   @interface viewViewController : UIViewController
2. Check to be sure you’re connecting the `delegate` and `datasource` properties from `tableView` to File’s Owner.

Comment: What do you mean by FileOwner?  Sorry, I am kinda new at this.

Comment: Also, I am using storyboard if that helps any.

Comment: @blake305 He means to whomever is going to implement the protocol methods, i.e. the delegate, which, in your case, is viewViewController.  If you are unable to wire up the delegate using Storyboard, in `viewDidLoad` of viewViewController, just do  `_tableView.delegate = self` and `_tableView.dataSource = self` - assuming that you included the protocols in the header: `@interface viewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Comment: If you use storyboard you should connect this properties to `viewcontroller`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by the UITableView being connected to your instance variable.  If you mean wired up from the XIB then you maybe getting "interference" from the overridden getter method that you have created.  You may want to put an NSlog to see if that method is being called.  if that is the case, the frame of the new table view that you are alloc/inviting is of zero size and I don't see anywhere in your code that you change the frame size.

good luck!

Comment: I did an NSLog right after `- (UITableView *)tableView {` and it didn't get called.  What should I do?

Comment: Then you will want to follow tomasz-wojtkowiak advice and make sure you implement the various UITableView protocol and data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing UITableViewController instead of UIViewController.

Comment: Explain?  I have no UITableViewController.  I have a UITableView in a UIViewController because it benefits what I am doing.

Comment: Sorry about that. If you need to use a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController then I think Tomasz's answer is correct. You need to be a delegate of UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource as Tomasz said.